# Что делать с форком после сливания моего pull request'а?

Tags: git, github

Форкнул проект, сделал в нем изменения, создал пулл реквест, его смерджили. Что мне теперь делать с форком этого проекта в моих репозиториях? Я могу его удалять? Просто меня смущает фраза "This will permanently delete the smellyshovel/language-javascript repository, wiki, issues, and comments, and remove all collaborator associations.", а особенно ее концовка, мол, все collaborator associations будут удалены. Как быть?

Comment: Да не, если форк больше никак не используется, то его можно спокойно удалять. Правда, многие (в том числе и я) предпочитают не удалять

Comment: @andreymal а можно потом постороннему человеку где-нибудь в моем профиле посмотреть мои контрибуции в другие проекты?

Comment: Посмотрел у человека, удалившего форк — вроде бы да, отображается https://i.imgur.com/EjemzQ3.png Был форк репозитория andreymal/tabun_api, после принятия мной пулл-реквеста форк удалили

Comment: @andreymal nice. Спасибо. В ответ бы написали, что ли

Comment: Думаю, кто-нибудь может написать более конкретный ответ, обоснованный больше чем просто «вроде бы»)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваш вклад в оригинальный atom/language-javascript навсегда останется в нем, потому что коммиты просто так не пропадают из гита.

Поскольку вклад сохранится, то и статистика останется на месте. Даже через много лет можно будет увидеть, что такого-то числа ваш коммит попал в вышеуказанный репозиторий. И ваше имя будет в проекте на вкладке Contributors.

> все collaborator associations будут удалены

Речь о людях, которым вы выдали права на пуш в ваш проект. У вас таких людей наверняка не было, как и задач, вики и прочего. Потерять вы можете только другие ветки, кроме той, что замержили в оригинальный репозиторий.

Вы всегда можете форкнуть репозиторий заново, так что нет никакого смысла «держать место». Но и удалять не обязательно — GH не ограничивает место и денег за форки публичных репозиториев не берет. Делайте как вам удобно.

Comment: Все понятно, благодарю

Comment: @smellyshovel кстати, название оригинального репозитория я так и нашел, вы же удалили форк.

Comment: Простите, но вы ведь сами написали в первом абзаце "... оригинальный atom/language-javascript ..."

Comment: @smellyshovel ну да. "Так и нашел" != "так и не нашел". )